# Will -Wpedantic do anything when compiling with a non-extension -std?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-pedantic

If I compile my C or C++ code with GCC, using `-std=c99` or `-std=c++11` or some other proper ISO standard rather than a GNU extension - will `-Wpedantic` issue more warnings that I would usually get? e.g. With `-W`, `-Wall` or `-Wall -Wextra`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using `-pedantic` makes GCC stricter. In [GCC 8.2](https://godbolt.org/z/EgkqxW), `int foo(void) { return ({3;}); }` compiles without complaint using just `-Wall -std=c11` but gets this warning with `-pedantic` added:

> warning: ISO C forbids braced-groups within expressions [-Wpedantic]

(The feature used, statement expressions, is intended for use in macros. It is used in my example solely as proof-of-principle.)

Comparing and contrasting:

- Using `-std=gnu11`, for example, requests a **non-standard** version of C.
- Using `-std=c11` requests a **standard** version of C. The C standard permits, and even invites, extensions, so you may still use certain GNU extensions with `-std=c11`.
- Adding `-pedantic` requests the compiler warn about certain GNU extensions and “traditional” features that it otherwise permits.

The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options) also suggests GCC may be lax about certain warnings it should issue with standard C, and `-pedantic` causes it to issue all warnings required by strict ISO C.

There may be additional variations; I am not an expert on GCC dialects and switches.